# How to properly benchmark / stresstest single-page web application

Tags: apache, knockout.js, benchmarking, single-page-application, stress-testing

I am somehow familiar with benchmarking/stress testing traditional web application and I find it relatively easy to start estimating maximum load for it. With tools I am familiar ([Apache ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html), [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)) I can get a rough estimate of the number of request/second a server with a standard app can handle. I can come up with user story, create a list of page I would like to check and benchmark them separately. A lot of information can be found on the internet how to go from novice like me to a master.

But in my opinion a lot of things is different when benchmarking single page application. The main entry point is the most expensive request, because the user loads majority of things needed for proper app experience (or at least in my app it is this way). After it navigation to other places is just ajax request, waiting for json, templating. So time to window load is not important anymore.

To add problems to this, I was not able to find any resources how people do it properly.

In my particular case I have a SPA written with knockout, and sitting on apache server (most probably this is irrelevant). I would like to have rough estimate how many users can my app on the particular server handle. I am not looking for a tool recommendation (also it would be nice), I am looking for experienced person to share his insight about benchmarking process.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test this application just like you would test any other web application, as you said - identify the common use cases, prepare scripts for them, run in the appropriate mix and analyze the results.

Web-applications can break in many different ways for different reasons. You are speculating that the first page load is heavy and the rest is just small ajax. From experience I can tell you that this is sometimes misleading - for example, you can find that the heavy page is coming from cache and the server is not working hard for it, but a small ajax response requires a lot of computing power or long running database query or has some locking in the code that cause it to break or be slow under load - that's why we do load testing.

You can do this with any load testing tool, ideally one that can handle those types of script with many dynamic values. My personal preference is WebLOAD by [RadView](http://radview.com)

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with similar scenario, SPA application where first page loads and there after everything is done by just requesting for other html pages and/or web service calls to get the data.

My goal is to stress test the web server and DB server.

My solution is to just create request for those html pages(very low performance issue, IMO, since they are static and they can be cached for a very long time in the browser) and web service call requests. Biggest load will come from the request for data/processing via the web service call requests.

Capture all the requests for html and web service calls using a tool like fiddler, and use any load test tools(like JMeter) to run these requests using as many virtual users as you want to test your application with.